# how we load machine learning Model .sav file with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I want to load Machine Learning model already saved as .sav file in spark
i used

```
val loaded_model = Pipeline.load("model_final.sav")
```

or

```
val loaded_model = PipelineModel.load("model_final.sav")
```

i meet exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/Pipeline$
    at migration2$.main(migration2.scala:61)
    at migration2.main(migration2.scala)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: scala 2.11 not java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `provided` from your dependency. So the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
```

Should be changed to:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0"
```